# Is it normal for CSV writing in python to take so much time?

Tags: python, csv

I have a code snipplet

```
import csv
...
    with open(outpath + outname + "_results.csv","w+") as my_csv:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(my_csv, delimiter = '|')
        csvWriter.writerows(zip(
            np.asarray(id_list), 
            np.asarray(ground_truth_list), 
            np.asarray(prediction_list)))
```

The 3 arrays correspond to ML predictions with the ground truth and the data IDs attached. The writer works okay-ish, its formatting is pretty awful, but we worked around it in the postprocessing. The main problem, however, is that it takes several hours for this code to complete the CSV when the arrays are 100M+. The resulting file is around 3-4 GB. Can this be accelerated somehow? Or is it reasonable for the writing to take this much time?

Comment: What exactly are the types of the three `..._list` variables?

Comment: Sorry for the harsh words, but the _thing_ you're doing is unreasonable. You're serializing arrays of numbers into text, and then formatting _that_ text separately, and then doing some postprocessing afterwards? Please use a binary format...

Comment: The performance issue is most likely in this:  `zip(np.asarray(id_list), np.asarray(ground_truth_list), np.asarray(prediction_list))`   Not in the writing of the CSV.  It looks like you are assembling a huge data structure in memory that will probably require some multiple of 4GB to construct.  If you don't have enough RAM, that coud lead to thrashing.

Comment: @StephenC Well, `zip` isn't the big allocation here, it just returns an iterator.

Comment: But the `asarray` calls ....

Comment: The lists are actual python lists, sorry for not mentioning. I don't remember why I had used np.asarray on them for the CSV, but the postprocessing is done in a separate step in multiple ways, so the file is needed to be saved in some way. Memory is not a problem, the code is executed on a server machine with several hundreds of GBs.

Edit: I can observe the CSV file slowly growing in size, so I assume the writing is the slow not allocations.

Comment: @oliver.c Please then reconsider your entire pipeline to not use text-based formats such as CSV – you're wasting a lot of time, energy and memory on that.

Comment: @AKX What do you recommend?

Comment: @oliver.c To begin with, you'd probably have an okay time with just `pickle`ing those 3 lists one after the other into a file: `with open("x.pickle", "wb") as f: for l in (id_list, ground_truth_list, prediction_list): pickle.dump(l, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)` – and then you'd load them from an `f` with 3 consecutive `pickle.load(f)` calls.

Comment: But since you are able to `np.asarray` them, see [`np.savez`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) too.

Comment: @AKX Thanks! These do not exactly answer to my question, but help with my problem nevertheless. There is only a few places in the pipeline where the CSV output is necessary (human readability), for the other parts I will incorporate your pickle suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to get a sense for how less performant asarray is:

```py
import csv

list1 = ["aaaaaaAAAAA"] * 100_000_000
list2 = ["bbbbbbBBBBB"] * 100_000_000
list3 = ["ccccccCCCCC"] * 100_000_000

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["A", "B", "C"])
    writer.writerows(zip(list1, list2, list3))
```

Just creating the lists in the first few lines only takes 5 seconds.

On my Macbook Air M1 (w/dual-channel SSD) that ran in 40.6 seconds and used 2.4 GB of RAM.  The output CSV was 3.4 GB on disk.

Using asarray:

```py
...
from numpy import asarray

    ...
    writer.writerows(zip(asarray(list1), asarray(list2), asarray(list3)))
```

That ran in 109.9 seconds and used 15.6 GB of RAM.

So, I don't get why **just the code you shared** is taking hours. I can imagine some processes before that (in the "..."), like generating the lists, might be chewing up some time.

Comment: I can see when the CSV output file is created which should be when the execution reaches the line "with open(...)" right? Because that's when the code slows down. I can observe said CSV file growing megabyte by megabyte throughout the hours.

There is indeed a long loop before that line, which creates the lists. However the CSV writing starts after this loop, not inside it.

Comment: Update: thanks to your example, I realized my lists were actually lists of one-element lists which resulted in the significant slow down. So instead of "list1 = ["aaaaaaAAAAA"] * 100_000_000" they were "list1 = [["aaaaaaAAAAA"]] * 100_000_000". Thank you!

Comment: @oliver.c, hmm. I presume you fixed that... did that also fix the formatting issues you were having?

Comment: Yes! It was a stupid mistake on my part. I've written the code years ago with barely any experience in python and it seems like a refactoring is due.